# Element must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

As I work on this project I keep getting an error saying:

> Element 'Customer' must have no character or element information item
>   [children], because the type's content type is empty.

I am not sure why this is not working seeing I followed the notes and it looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="Customer" type="xs:string">  
  <xs:complexType>  
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>  
  </xs:complexType>  
</xs:element>
```

I know it's saying I can't have the `type="xs:string"` in there but then how do I make it have to have a string?

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to fix your XSD's definition of `Customer`:  Use `xs:simpleContent` with `xs:complexType` rather than `xsl:element/@type` in your definition (customer.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The above XSD will then consider content such as the following valid:

```
<Customer id="123">This is a string.</Customer>
```